# python .max() giving multiple values as opposed to one

Tags: python, pandas

I have to read in a CSV file and print the highest value. However, when I do I get two values rather than one.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

A = pd.read_csv("Test4.csv")
B=A.max()
print("The maximum usage rate is: ", B)
```

Output:
The maximum usage rate is:  1.000041738    1.000369

dtype: float64

Process finished with exit code 0

CSV file:

1.000041738

1.000354758

1.000368539

1.000013902

Im curious how i should modify my code to give one single value. Thank you for any and all help

Comment: by default pandas returns column max values. Use `A.values.max()` or `A.max().max()` to get max of all columns

Comment: thank you, works now

Comment: `A.values.max()` or `A.max().max()` will NOT give the correct maximum if the maximum value is in the first row of the csv file. If you were to put `10` as the first entry in the csv the results would still give you a maximum of `1.000368539`.

Answer (score 0):

The `1.000041738` is actually the name of the columns because you are reading in the first record as the column name.

Instead of

```
A = pd.read_csv("Test4.csv")
```

Try

```
A = pd.read_csv("Test4.csv", names=['values'])
```

and `A['values'].max()` will give one single number.